# Chinese doesn't display in Ubuntu with Chromebook Pixel

Tags: chinese, chromebook

I install Ubuntu (Unity as desktop) alongside with Chrome OS for my Chromebook Pixel, following the instructions on this webpage: http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook/2013/05/14

The Chinese characters don't display correctly anywhere, though the Chinese language support has been installed. The Chinese characters don't show up in web pages, they do not even show up in the Language Support panel. [image]

I have no idea how to fix this. Could anyone help me fixing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this. Its the latest.

http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/05/chrubuntu-one-script-to-rule-them-all_31.html

I donated to the writers paypal.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.